# show user list command cisco 5500 ASA

Tags: users, cisco-asa, cisco-vpn

simple issue.. I'm a noob

I am running a cisco 5500 ASA which is used to manage a VPN, I need the command used to check the current user list. 
I think it might be an 'access-list', if so I have no idea what the name of the access list is, is there a way to show the access lists?

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean you want to show the local users setup on the ASA correct?

to do this you would go in enable mode with the `en` command. then issue the `sh aaa local user` command.

In response to your comment: do you mean `sh run username` ?

Comment: Halfway there :) ... that does show the user names but it doesnt show the other information I require. I have run this command before and it shows me the hashed password, a numeral to show their access level and there actual name..

Answer (score 1):

the command was `sh running-config user`

now I just got to figure out how to add a new entry to this list ;_;

Comment: To add a new entry enter config mode with `conf t`.
Then, enter the command `username (desired username) password (desired password) privilege (desired priv)`.  Privilige is 1 through 15, with 15 being 'root' access.